# Browser-populated form input text gets styled differently, makes input fields unreadable

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm working on the my site which is done with a black background. I've changed the coloring on the form input fields.  However, when I return to a page with saved text in a field, the background color becomes white, and the text color stays a light color (grey) and thus becomes somewhat unreadable.

e.g.

```
input{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
```

Presumably there is some way to style this "text that is pre-populated by the browser based on previous responses", but I don't know what css allows access to it, or what it would be called to search for it.

Tried: Searching through the css pseudo-classes, google searching through form styling tutorials, etc.  Browser inspecting the form elements for relevant user-agent css, nothing.

Point me in the right direction?

Comment: How/where did you change the background color in the first place?

Comment: Is this happening on all browsers or just a specific one?

Comment: Edited with css response.  I'm actually only getting this in google chrome now, so perhaps that's the problem, I thought it was happening in firefox as well, but perhaps I was mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a browser behavior, and I don't believe it can be controlled via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The file input element is a bitch to customize. There are [workarounds](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) but they involve a lot of hackery. If you really need to customize the look and feel of your fields, try a flash based uploader like [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org) or [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com).

Comment: K, though I'm not dealing with any file upload stuff, just plain text-input fields that I want to match to a black background.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question right. Whenever somebody complains about not being able to style something, I automatically think of `file`. I believe the selection colour is indeed one of the very few things that you can't style.